# Log Exceptions When Application is unable to connect to Database

Tags: c#, exception, model-view-controller

I am developing a MVC application. I have a controller which has methods in it. Controller methods invoke repository methods.Repository methods connect to database to fetch the information.

As and when there is an exception in the methods , I log that information in the database log table, but I did come across a scenario wherein application is not able to connect to the database itself in that case what are the option to log that exception and how do I handle that.

When I use fiddler and trace the request I can find out Controller method is throwing an exception and I can trace the root cause looking at response but in production environment how do I handle this scenario. How & where do I log if application is unable to connect to the database.

Comment: How about to use logging in file?

Comment: "if application is unable to connect to the database" Can  you specify whether the connection failed or whether the insert command failed.
If the connection failed than there is something more serious that you should look into then tackle the logging

Comment: @DaniDev: Surely the first step of finding out what that more seriosu thing is is to log details of the problem? I mean, I assume the logging will include logging the inability to connect to the database including the relevant exception details...

Comment: IMHO, Not necessarily. Let me clarify, If Naga clarifies that the only the insert of the exception into the DB fails and the connection is fine then it's just that some bugginess with the Transaction code. If in fact the DB connection that the relies on (for operation of the entire app) is failing (intermittently) then I think he would want to tackle that issue.

Comment: As far as logging once you clear up the DB connectivity. You could implement a text/XML log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

That is for webforms but you could easily do something similar in MVC

Answer (score 1):

You really should be writing to the event logs, preferably with a custom event source so your server teams can easily sort and find issues in the event viewer.

It is extremely simple to write a logging class to do this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307024/how-to-write-to-an-event-log-by-using-visual-c

The only "gotcha" that no one mentions is that when you use a custom even source, your application pool's identity must have access to create the source on the machine or that will fail and be place under a generic error. Some people like to prep the machine by creating it themselves, others like to do it via powershell script as a deployment step. Whatever floats your boat.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-eventlog

The only logging you should be doing in the DB is audit trail logging for your application.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do it. I'll put a list of which I can think on top of my head. A few options are more important for localhost (during development from your machine). I tend to include network issues in this phase. There are a few times when the dev's machine has network issues and it couldn't make use of the other options. Once it's in production (Intranet apps should still includes Internet connectivity issues), clients are obviously accessing it using the Internet.

1. **Advanced Options:** Use advanced services like Azure Application Insight. This is very powerful as you can set custom events and generate reports/filter on per userId basis too. I'm not sure if there are similar options available on Amazon or Google cloud etc. May be someone else can shed some light here. That's my preferred way. It can log issues per method basis too and generate alerts. Very handy. [What is Application Insights?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview)
2. **Online Data Logging Services**: These can be useful too but I can't think of their benefits over Options 1. There are many option here. Just google this term. I used a few of them years ago in my robotics projects (year 2005ish).
3. **DataStorage Way**: Use simple storage like Azure Blob storage or any other NoSQL storage if you want. I'm sure Amazon or other cloud services provide it. Just push the data without worrying about creating table schema etc. Once you have your connection set, there are lesser chances that a good service provider like (Azure, Amazon or Google) won't have their storage available for you to log.
   It is [Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) on Amazon I think.
   It used to be Blobstore on Google but now they claim to have [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) with advanced options. 
   I haven't used it though so don't know much about it. Anybody!??
4. **Let you know directly**: If you don't want to store the data anywhere, sending an email with the errors can be an option. Also, this is only free option I can think of which can inform you remotely without having you logging to the server. If you want to play smart, you can direct these emails to log bugs/task in your Agile board. 

   That's my preferred way. I do it in conjunction with Option 1, to log a bug in TeamServices. TeamServices can then let the assigned Lead via it's own notification service. This you would do anyways to report a bug, so why not let your app do it for you with all the info available at that moment.

   You can make use of services like https://zapier.com/ which has direct integration with Jira/TS/Bootcamp etc. There are many free tools as well.
5. **Local File**: Create a date-stamped file on the server. This is helpful when there is no Internet connectivity. Very helpful (one of the few option available) in case of localhost environment or Intranet Websites. If the machine has access to the Internet and you want to go with this option, you can also auto sync this file using Google Drive/Dropbox/OneDrive or any other option of your choice. Just avoiding logging on to the server every minute to check if there is a file!
6. **Server/System Logging**: As mentioned by @Riddle03, logging in Application Events Logs can be useful. This can also be useful in localhost/Intranet only environment.
7. **Why would you do it option**: Let your application Tweet it and let the world know that your system has just encountered an issue and you're going to be busy fixing it!

Where to put the code to log it? Totally depends how your application is configured. I do it via a LoggerService in my Data Bus, which is responsible for establishing any Db connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could log under the Application Event Logs in the server, if you have access to it.